# Choose injection constructor based on setting in .config file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, dependency-injection, ninject, ninject.web.mvc

I have a MCV3 app that uses Ninject as a DI container.

I have one object that has 2 constructors (each with 1 parameter)

```
public MyObject(IDependencyOne dep){}
public MyObject(IDependencyTwo dep){}
```

How can I make Ninject choose one of the two constructors based on some boolean value read from web.config file at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2147855/1182982), it says : Ninject doesn't have XML configuration.

> **Free yourself from XML**
>
> Most other .NET dependency injection frameworks are designed around the use of XML to declare type bindings. Rather than forcing you to write cumbersome and error-prone text, Ninject arms you with a fluent interface, which lets you connect the pieces of your application using full-fledged code. This means you can take advantage of the features of the IDE and compiler, like code completion and type-safety.

There's been a general trend (among the folks I know or follow, anyway) to moving IoC bindings into code and out of XML. Mostly b/c you gain intellisense and runtime feedback of screw-ups.

I haven't used it but there are release candidates for [Ninject.Extensions.Xml](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.xml) which allows you to setup your mappings in xml. However I would generally shy away from doing it this way. There's also [Ninject.Extensions.Conventions](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.conventions) which might be what you're after.

Source :

[Ninject and configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639689/ninject-and-configuration)

[Ninject and XML configuration Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4647972/ninject-and-xml-configuration-binding)

Comment: This is not what I meant, NInject is fluently configured but what bindings to configure needs to be decided dynamically at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You'd use the [constructor selection syntax](http://www.planetgeek.ch/2011/05/28/ninject-constructor-selection-preview/) with Conditional Bindings - see [this related question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8391521/ninject-conditional-binding) and [the relevant wiki section on Contextual Binding](https://github.com/ninject/ninject/wiki/Contextual-Binding).